# Moving emails with specific number in subject to a specific folder with the corresponding number

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, vba, archiving

I get emails in shared inbox containing a number in the subject (like 9921635).

These emails are archived to subfolders, which are part of the shared inbox, that also contain this number.

Sometimes the folder is not yet present. In this case a simple error message would be enough (I will create it). Most of the emails can be put in an already present folder.

I want the rule to run only when I want it, not every time an email arrives. Simple like selecting a bunch of emails with the same subject and run the rule/macro so I do not have to search for the folder in our vast archive.

I think rules are not enough to do this, maybe some VBA code?

Comment: Do you know what all the possible numerical strings are or do you need it to look for them? Are they all the same length? Do they have the same prefix or suffix? [Take a look at this as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625704/vba-outlook-2010-detect-a-code-in-emails-subject)

Comment: Mostly they are in a form Dxx, Dxxx, Dxxxx or 992xxxx. Thanks for the link! I just had a glance at it, it seems that this script runs always and applies to emails when they arrive. This wouldn't be good as first the emails need attention and owner who solves them. Only then they can be archived. I don't have any experience in VB so it might be easy to modify the script but I really don't know how. Can you advise? Thanks.

Comment: you could set a rule (or macro I guess) to find those strings and move to a folder when it is run. I can think about it a little

Comment: Yeah but the problem with the rule is that it can find only a particular string and move it to a particular folder. It doesn't know dynamic adressing. I was trying believe me. I'm not saying it is not possible I just haven't found a way how to do it with rules. Well macro is even worse than VB :)